# mysql not allowing me to pull from two separate tables and compare them

Tags: mysql

In screenshots and projects, projectId is the connector. I get the error below when I run the following sql code:

SQL Code:

```
SELECT * FROM screenshots s, projects p WHERE s.projectId == p.projectId ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC
```

Error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '== p.projectId ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC' at line 1
>
> SELECT * FROM screenshots s, projects p WHERE s.projectId ==
>   p.projectId ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC
>
> Filename:
>   C:\Workspace\htdocs\Jan-2012\nurbell\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because the [SQL equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) is `=`, not `==`.

It's also highly recommended to use explicit JOIN syntax to associate tables, rather than the implicit join syntax you're using. So, for example, instead of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM screenshots s, projects p 
WHERE s.projectId = p.projectId 
ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC
```

You should use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM screenshots s
JOIN projects p ON s.projectId = p.projectId 
ORDER BY s.idscreenshot DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a single `=` sign instead of `==`